Why does non-interactive replace-regexp replace newlines with ^A's?
I'm putting the last finishing touches on the formatting operations in a package I'm developing and one of the things I'd like to do is replace a regexp of the form
"\"\\(
+\\)\""

with its interior sub-expression, so effectively remove quotation signs around strings of newlines. The issue is, when I use this regexp interactively (with the double backslashes replaced by single ones) this works perfectly well, but if I do something like evaluate the first lisp-expression in this code block:
(replace-regexp "\"\\(
+\\)\"" "\1")

test1 "

" test2

The lower part evaluates to
test1  test2

In case this isn't displayed in the browsers of readers, the two test's are separated by a control code ^A. I've checked, and this happens regardless of the numbers of newlines. I've read that in ASCII ^A means "Start of Heading". Why does Emacs replace my newlines with heading starts in non-interactive use?
I'm using GNU Emacs 31.0.50, but I've also tested this on Emacs 26.

I found the issue, it's pretty prosaic: I had to escape the backslash in the replacement text. Since I didn't do this, I guess it inserted the character whose character code is 1, which is ^A.
